# JS Page won't redirect using location.href?

Tags: javascript, function, url, redirect

I'm learning Javascript, and this basic redirect isn't doing anything.

The alert fires, but no version of 'page redirect' code I've tried seems to be working.
I've tried every version of location.href, document.location.href, window.location, etc etc....

I just want to switch urls when user input == '85.5'. But despite hours of trying, it just won't work.
What am I missing here?
Thanks!

I'm calling this function in a form element like so:

```
<form onsubmit="showInput()">
    <input type="text" id="question" name="inputz">
</form>

function showInput(){
    var InputNumber = document.getElementById("question").value;
    if(InputNumber == '85.5'){
      alert("You escaped"); //this works
      alert(InputNumber); //this works
      window.location.href ='/Survive_The_Swamp3.html'; //this does NOT work
      return false;
    }
    else {
      alert(InputNumber);
      document.location.href ="https://i.redd.it/twrza9clfsh21.jpg"; //also doesn't work
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: maybe you should provide fullpath to location,eg:`https://example.com/Survive_The_Swamp3.html`

Comment: @nay That link is a relative path to an html file in the same folder, but neither it nor the full path url below it, in the 'else' statement will redirect :(
Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: `window.location.href ='/Survive_The_Swamp3.html', true;` That's not valid syntax.
`window.location.href ='/Survive_The_Swamp3.html'` should suffice. If you open the inspector and put `window.location.href ='/Survive_The_Swamp3.html'` in the console what happens? Because it seems fine when I try it out.

Comment: I mean build the fullpath to redirect,maybe location not accept a relative path

Comment: @Fozzle So when I put the window.location.href ='/Survive_The_Swamp3.html' directly into the console, it seems to work fine! So my function just isn't firing that part correctly for some reason?

Comment: Have you tried `location.replace('http://www.google.com/');`

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `window.location.href`.

**You don't have anything that submits the form**. So the `onsubmit` handler is never called.

Forms are submitted when there's an `<input type="submit">` which will be rendered as a button. Forms can also be submitted if there's a `<button>` inside the form. If neither of these exist then the form is never submitted unless you manually submit the form by calling the form's `.submit()` method in javascript.

For your code to trigger you need to wait for the `<input>` change event:

```
<input type="text" id="question" name="inputz" onchange="showInput()">
```

However there is a subtle issue with how `onchange` events work. They are triggered **BEFORE** the input gets the new value. As such when your user type `"85.5"` your event handler will see `"85."`. To get the current value you need to read it from the event object:

```
function showInput(event){
    var InputNumber = event.target.value;

    //...
```

The reason `onchange` works this way is to allow you to cancel the event thus preventing the `<input>` from getting the value. For example you can use this feature to prevent the user from entering something that is not a number.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate the feedback and information from everybody; however the only thing I was able to finally get to work was using the following configuration:

```
<form onsubmit="showInput(); return false"> //maybe return false here made the difference?
     <input type="text" id="question" name="inputz" >
</form>

    
    function showInput(){
    var InputNumber = document.getElementById("question").value;
    if(InputNumber == '85.5'){
      alert("You escaped");
      window.location.href='/Survive_The_Swamp3.html';
    }
```